Access to published port on container sharing a network stack
I am trying to create an http proxy and vpn tunnel with tinyproxy and wireguard in a docker-compose. The tinyproxy server exposes port 8888 and the wireguard exposes 51820. The idea is to access the proxy from the host (dt1.dawson) and its network.
To test it, I use curl:
curl --proxy dt1.dawson:8888 http://google.com

I'm trying to use a suggested solution where wireguard is the base container attached to the bridge network, and tinyproxy relies on wireguard and shares the network stack via network_mode: service:wireguard.
I tried making tinyproxy use the wireguard network stack, but I cannot access either container from the host, e.g. curl --proxy dt1.dawson:8888 http://google.com hangs.
docker-compose:
version: '3.6'
services:
  tinyproxy:
    image: docker.io/kalaksi/tinyproxy
    network_mode: "service:wireguard"

    volumes:
      - ./tinyproxy-etc/tinyproxy.conf:/etc/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.conf
    #   # If not using docker-compose for secrets, you can still manually mount a file containing the password.
    #   - ./secrets/auth_password:/run/secrets/auth_password:ro

  wireguard:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/wireguard:latest
    container_name: wireguard
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE #optional
    network_mode: "bridge"
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Etc/UTC
      - LOG_CONFS=true #optional
    volumes:
      - ./wg_config:/config
      - /lib/modules:/lib/modules #optional
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
      - 51820:51820/udp
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
    restart: unless-stopped  

NOTE Docker does not allow port mapping on tinyproxy b/c network_mode. Instead, wireguard maps port 8888 for tinyproxy to use.
The problem is that I cannot access tinyproxy from dt1.dawson:8888. It hangs. However, if I use the IP address for tinyproxy, it works!
curl --proxy 172.17.0.3:8888 http://google.com

I verified the network interfaces inside the containers are good. I don't understand why I can't connect to dt1.dawson:8888, but I can connect to 172.17.0.3:8888. I also verified that dt1.dawson is listening to port 8888 when the containers are running, but not listening when they are stopped.
